# What is the meaning of "spread" in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

I read a sentence in "The Hindu" which was:

This year's interim budget is being regarded as a big spread for farmers.

Does it mean "extent or amount of something" or "a large meal (although not in literal sense)?

Comment: *Spread*, in finance means the difference between two prices, rates, or yields. In this case it means that the budget is quite different from before, for the farmers.

Comment: The supplied context suggests the ‘meal’ sense.